# Hybridauth supports Facebook strict mode for redirect URIs?

Tags: php, facebook, hybridauth

Facebook announced that:

In March, they are making a security update to your app settings that will invalidate calls from URIs not listed in the Valid OAuth redirect URIs field below.This update comes in response to malicious activity they saw on their platform, and they want to protect your app or website by requiring a new strict mode for redirect URIs.

But after activating the Strict Mode option in Facebook Login -> Settings, The login action doesn't work no more.

I think this is because the redirect URI used now is

```
http://mysite/auth/?hauth_done=Facebook
```

and in strict mode `?hauth_done=Facebook` is not allowed.

I'm using Hybridauth 2.8.2, is this strict mode supported in other version?

Thanks

Comment: Why would that not be allowed in strict mode? You just have to specify the _exact_ same URL as a Valid OAuth Redirect URI.

Comment: I've tried it and it doesn't work, I don't know why.

Comment: Check what actual value gets passed for the parameter in the login dialog URL. Make sure it is properly URL encoded.